# while implementing facebook sharing in web app Error get The parameter app_id is required

Tags: javascript, java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

I am working in java and jsp building a web application. 
 In my web application i am working on facebook sharing functionality.
I have done with the facebook login. But getting problem in sharing

The error is `The parameter app_id is required` A popup comes with the error message and the url in the popup browser is follow

```
(https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=&display=popup&e2e=......)
```

My code is 
In HIML

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

 <button type="button" id="btnfbShare" class="btn sign-btn fr">Share on Facebook</button>
```

IN js

The facebook sdk initialization code

```
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                  appId      : '10761986057291117',
                  xfbml      : true,
                  version    : 'v2.4'
                });
              };

              (function(d, s, id){
                 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
               }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And on share button click

```
 $("#btnfbShare").click(function(event){
                      alert("in share");
                      FB.ui(
                              {

                               method: 'share',
                               href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/'
                             }, function(response){});

                   });
```

what can be the problem as i am providing the app id at the time of sdk installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution,

Need to write again initialization on button click

```
$("#btnfbShare").click(function(event){                         
    FB.init({
        appId      : '10761986057291117',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.4'
    });

    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/'
        }, function(response){});
});
```